# Finding mean of centers in k-means

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

Since K-means algorithm is susceptible to the order of the columns, I am executing it 100 times and storing the final centers of each iteration in an array.

I want to calculate the mean centers of the array , but I am getting only a value using this

```
a =np.mean(center_array)
vmean = np.vectorize(np.mean)
vmean(a)
```

How can I calculate the median centers?

This is the structure of my centers array

```
[[ 1.39450598,  0.65213679,  1.37195399,  0.02577591,  0.17637011,
         0.44572744,  1.50699298, -0.02577591, -0.17637011, -0.48222273,
        -0.14651225, -0.12975152],
       [-0.40910528, -0.18480587, -0.40459059,  1.00860933, -0.91902229,
        -0.13536744, -0.45108061, -1.00860933,  0.91902229,  0.11367937,
         0.19771608,  0.23722015],
       [-0.46264585, -0.23289607, -0.45219009,  0.0290917 ,  1.08811289,
        -0.14996175, -0.48998741, -0.0290917 , -1.08811289,  0.19925625,
        -0.14748408, -0.1943812 ]]), array([[ 0.20004497, -0.12493111,  0.99146416, -0.91902229, -0.17537297,
         0.11154588, -0.41348193, -0.99146416, -0.45307083, -0.4091783 ,
         0.18579957,  0.91902229]],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the axis that contains the final centers of each iteration, otherwise the `np.mean` is calculated over the flattened array, resulting in a single value. From [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

> Returns the average of the array elements. The average is taken over the flattened array by default, otherwise over the specified axis.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.rand(5,3)

out1 = x.mean()
print(out1, out1.shape)
# 0.49456456164468965 ()

out2 = x.mean(axis=1) # rows
print(out2, out2.shape)
# [0.68574946 0.30355721 0.50845826 0.56618897 0.40886891] (5,)

out3 = x.mean(axis=0) # columns
print(out3, out3.shape)
# [0.51435949 0.44116654 0.52816766] (3,)
```